# Where to answer specific question about already described problem?

Tags: discussion, support

There is quite well-known problem about [applying transforms](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) which also has answers about different use cases ([rigid bodies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7307/1245), [UV unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7967/1245)).

Recently there was added question about [unexpected working of symmetry in Sculpt mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/85126/1245) which in the end appeared to be yet another consequence of the pretty much the same problem - unapplied transforms.

My question is about how to handle questions like this one. From one side, [applying transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) question is canonical and addresses multiple aspects of the problem. From another side, I think that it's too general while unexpected symmetry question is much more localized.

What should be done in these situations?

- answering the question?
- just flagging as duplicate?
- flagging as duplicate and adding another answer to the canonical question?

So generally my question is about handling localized questions regarding more general ones.

Comment: I guess this is somewhat related https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say answer it where it is (and link to the more general question).

Two questions can have the same answer but still be different questions. One of these questions is about a sculpting issue, the other is about transforms. Going with the policy of "flag/tag the question, not the answer", I think that these particular two questions are not duplicates.

I'd also say "to keep sculpting transforms straight" is a perfectly good answer to the latter question.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Looks like I should ask here on meta about each situation like that as they often tend to be unique and I can't decide.